# How can I use bash history to run a command using arguments from history?

Tags: bash, history

How can I use the bash history to run a command with the arguments from a command in the history?

I know that I can use `!!` to rerun the last command, but how can I run a new command with those arguments?

eg, I first run:

```
~/somefolder/script.sh somefile
```

I want to quickly run

```
~/somefolder/script.sh anotherfile
```

I tried `!! anotherfile` but it didn't work.

Or even better, how can I run `!-2 newarguments` to run the second last history command with new arguments?

I don't want to use the arrows to scroll through the history then backspace over the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pick the command name, use the :0 modifier:

```
$ man bash
$ !!:0 csh
man csh
```

Chose all arguments with most recent command with !*

```
$ man sed awk perl
$ which !*
which sed awk perl
/usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/awk
/usr/bin/perl
```

Choose the 2nd command previously executed relative to the current command, and pick all its arguments with:

```
$ echo !-2:*
echo sed awk perl
sed awk perl
```

Choose the 3rd command previously executed relative to the current command, and pick its 2nd argument:

```
$ echo !-3:2
echo awk
awk
```

Choose the last command that began with "which" and plug in its 3rd argument:

```
$ echo !which:3
echo perl
perl
```

---

All that said, the answers to your two specific questions:

1. See the first example, above.
2. !-2:0 "new list of arguments"

Comment: Read the [BASh manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction).  ;-)  Just know that you first select a line, perform substitutions, and then refine that with modifiers, then maybe just print the result `:p`.  Explore matching lines with `!?text?`, or match an occurrence of the text anywhere in a history command's line to match the line.  Other variants match a line, then don't just grab pieces of the line, but perform a regular expression replacement before executing the command i.e. `!wh:gs/sed/tr/`, `which` command subs for sed, tr.

Answer (score -1):

If you press the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl-R** in the terminal, and type any unique portion of the command, it does reverse search and finds it for you. No need to scroll all the way.

Comment: Yes, I knew about Ctrl-R, but you still have to backspace to remove the arguments, which I specified in the question that I didn't want to do. Thanks for the answer anyway. BTW I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @localhost If an answer is not useful for your question, you should downvote it. That's how the system works; you wouldn't have to excuse yourself for it.

Comment: @slhck Possibly true to the letter of the law, but it seems a bit rude to downvote someone for making an honest effort. If I had not known about Ctrl-R, then jadelord's answer would still have helped me somewhat. Your point is well taken though.

Comment: It's an alternative, for the uninitiated. That's all. It's OK @localhost, and thanks.